# How to fire inputFieldChanged event of mydatepicker

Tags: angular, typescript, event-handling, dom-events

I am using [mydatepicker](https://github.com/kekeh/mydatepicker) in angular 2 for date type textbox and trying to call inputFieldChanged event of this datetimepicker.   It gets called when input(selected by datepicker ) is changed.

inputFieldChanged event do not get fired when I put some invalid date by keyboard in the text box and now remove all the text one by one using backbutton and when last character is removed from textbox it should fire the inputFieldChanged event, but no event gets fired.

You can check in the screenshot also, when I removed last character also 0, this event was supposed to fire and we should get the blank value in the console. Any possibility to find how to fire that event (or any other event) in case of last character removed (when we are putting the invalid date by keyboard.)

[image: Screenshot of event not getting fired.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted the bug on owner github issues forum and he solved this bug in latest  [release 2.0.27](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mydatepicker).

Answer (score 0):

You can use ViewChild of mydatepicker whichever component you are using like below

```
//Here you will get instance of myDatepicker

@ViewChild(MyDatePicker) myDatePicker: MyDatePicker;
```

I checked this library onIn event is output event and it is getting emitted from following functions of MyDatePicker component.

onUserDateInput()

updateDateValue()

You can use this instance if datepicker and access all the functionalities from this date picker.